# Nmap output format ip:port

Tags: awk, nmap

I need load ip list from file, scan it, and create output format such as `ip:port`. I tried this:

```
nmap -iL mylistwithip.txt -p 80,21 -oG -PS 80,21 | awk '/open/{print $2}' >` output.txt
```

but it gives me only "open" and that's all.

While I need only opened ports from list of IP addresses, for example:

```
192.168.2.1
192.168.2.2
192.168.2.3
```

after scan ports, sample `output.txt`:

```
192.168.2.1:80
192.168.2.1:21
192.168.2.3:80
```

(only scanned ip addresses with opened ports)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Quick and ugly hack to achieve that:

```
nmap -vv -iL mylistwithip.txt  | grep "Discovered open port" | awk {'print $6":"$4'} | awk -F/ {'print $1'} > output.txt
```

With `-vv` output includes lines like

```
Discovered open port 22/tcp on 192.168.2.1
Discovered open port 80/tcp on 192.168.2.1
Discovered open port 22/tcp on 192.168.2.107
Discovered open port 80/tcp on 192.168.2.107
```

First `awk` selects "ip address" and "port number/protocol" fields, and second cuts off "/protocol".

This will probably break in some future update of `nmap`. Using `-sG` (greppable output) would be a better idea.

Comment: I think it is overdose of grep and awk here. This could be done by single awk command too, I added it in here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this awk oneliner:

```
nmap -Pn -oG - 192.168.1.1 | awk '/open/{ s = $2; for (i = 5; i <= NF-4; i++) s = substr($i,1,length($i)-4) "\n"; split(s, a, "/"); print $2 ":" a[1]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

try one more solution with single awk only.

```
nmap -vv -iL file  | awk -F'[ /]' '/Discovered open port/{print $NF":"$4}'
```